# Configure brokerURL like bean method

Tags: java, spring, jms, activemq-classic

I need to configure JMS sender. But I must have opportunity to set up DNS name in properties file. Also i have parameters that should be added to DNS. I decided to create a bean that would return complete url to broker. But i have a start up problem. 
so this is my XML:

```
<bean id="path" class="com.promptlink.stbtp.Config" factory-method="getJMSPath"/>


<bean id="jmsConnectionFactory" class="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory">
    <property name="brokerURL" ref="path"/>
</bean>
```

and this is final link:

```
nio://10.20.6.192:9091?connectionTimeout=3000&amp;jms.useAsyncSend=true&amp;wireFormat.tightEncodingEnabled=false
```

if i will set the link directly as a value of a propertie - no problems. JMS start well. But when i am trying to pass the link as a bean - it crashes. with exception:

```
javax.jms.JMSException: Error while attempting to add new Connection to the pool
    at org.apache.activemq.jms.pool.PooledConnectionFactory.createJmsException(PooledConnectionFactory.java:251)
    at org.apache.activemq.jms.pool.PooledConnectionFactory.createConnection(PooledConnectionFactory.java:210)
    at org.apache.activemq.jms.pool.PooledConnectionFactory.createConnection(PooledConnectionFactory.java:189)
    at org.apache.activemq.jms.pool.PooledConnectionFactory.start(PooledConnectionFactory.java:271)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeCustomInitMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1706)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1645)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:839)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:538)
    at org.springframework.context.support.FileSystemXmlApplicationContext.<init>(FileSystemXmlApplicationContext.java:140)
    at org.springframework.context.support.FileSystemXmlApplicationContext.<init>(FileSystemXmlApplicationContext.java:84)
    at com.promptlink.stbtp.messaging.NodeMessageDispatcher.getInstance(NodeMessageDispatcher.java:20)
    at com.promptlink.stbtp.messaging.NodeMessageDispatcher.sendToWebapp(NodeMessageDispatcher.java:33)
    at com.promptlink.stbtp.Config.init(Config.java:170)
    at com.promptlink.stbtp.App.main(App.java:159)
Caused by: javax.jms.JMSException: Could not create Transport. Reason: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid connect parameters: {amp;wireFormat.tightEncodingEnabled=false, amp;jms.useAsyncSend=true}
    at org.apache.activemq.util.JMSExceptionSupport.create(JMSExceptionSupport.java:36)
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createTransport(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:317)
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createActiveMQConnection(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:330)
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createActiveMQConnection(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:303)
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createConnection(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:243)
    at org.apache.activemq.jms.pool.PooledConnectionFactory.createConnection(PooledConnectionFactory.java:259)
    at org.apache.activemq.jms.pool.PooledConnectionFactory$1.makeObject(PooledConnectionFactory.java:104)
    at org.apache.activemq.jms.pool.PooledConnectionFactory$1.makeObject(PooledConnectionFactory.java:84)
    at org.apache.commons.pool.impl.GenericKeyedObjectPool.addObject(GenericKeyedObjectPool.java:1748)
    at org.apache.activemq.jms.pool.PooledConnectionFactory.createConnection(PooledConnectionFactory.java:206)
    ... 24 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid connect parameters: {amp;wireFormat.tightEncodingEnabled=false, amp;jms.useAsyncSend=true}
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.TransportFactory.doConnect(TransportFactory.java:122)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.TransportFactory.connect(TransportFactory.java:64)
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createTransport(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:315)
    ... 32 more
```

So what am i doing wrong, and how to fix this problem? All i need  - it to pass the url to JMS broker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is to do with the configuration context. When you specify the value in XML
the 
`&amp;` 
is properly decoded to 
& 
by the XML parser. So the actual value passed to the brokerURL property will be nio://10.20.6.192:9091?connectionTimeout=3000&jms.useAsyncSend=true&wireFormat.tightEncodingEnabled=false

This is because & is a special character in XML and needs to be escaped

When using code to generate the URL make sure you use the right format

```
nio://10.20.6.192:9091?connectionTimeout=3000&jms.useAsyncSend=truewireFormat.tightEncodingEnabled=false
```

Comment: Yes! It is it! Your solution fixed all! Thank you!

Comment: But why do i need "&" character between `connectionTimeout=3000` and `jms.useAsyncSend=true`?